# Open sqlite database under root

Tags: android, sqlite, root

I'm trying to open sqlite database(/data/data/com.android.browser/databases/webview.db)
under root(sure, phone have rooted).

```
And i get an error:
03-22 20:51:55.215: E/Database(16710): sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/com.android.browser/databases/webview.db", &handle, 1, NULL) failed
```

---

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        EmployeeTable employeeTable = new EmployeeTable(this);
        System.out.println(employeeTable.databaseExist());//false

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```